# QNX server backup image

Tags: backup, qnx

I have a server with qnx 6.5

I want to use dd comand to take full os backup

What is right to `dd /dev/hd0`   or `dd /dev/hd07t` my aim is to have an image to be applied for other hardware

Other concern is if i take dd /dev/hd0  will this produce  a file with the same hdd size or the final size will be the data size only

Comment: Do you want to clone the full drive, or only a partition?

Comment: I want to build identical server butwith diffrent hardware specs ... So which one i should follow